# Minimal implementation of a Forge Viewer in React

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to make a minimal implementation of a viewer with React using this answer as example [Autodesk Forge Viewer and React components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984409/autodesk-forge-viewer-and-react-components)

Until now I'm able to show a model with a harcoded token and urn, but when I want to programmatically get a token I'm getting these errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLlR5MUVRR2NYUXhxeklIdlBFM1g2aUE_dmVyc2lvbj0xNw?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7

GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLlR5MUVRR2NYUXhxeklIdlBFM1g2aUE_dmVyc2lvbj0xNw?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000 net::ERR_FAILED
```

[image]

From my code I only access this endpoint in my server `api/forge/oauth`, I.m not directly using `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2` like the errors show.

And To prevent the CORS error for the only endpoint I'm using `api/forge/oauth` I already set the headers in my server, like this:

**SERVER CODE**

```
// Set up Express web server
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // aplication/json
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

// This is for web server to start listening to port 8080
app.set('port', 8080);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

**CLIENT CODE**

**Public HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/2.*/style.min.css?v=v7.*" type="text/css">
<!-- The Viewer JS -->
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/2.*/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/2.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Viewer from './Viewer'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="vContainer">
        <Viewer/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Viewer.js**

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import {initializeViewer} from './viewer-helper'

const Viewer = () => {
  const urn = 'dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLlR5MUVRR2NYUXhxeklIdlBFM1g2aUE_dmVyc2lvbj0xNw'
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeViewer(urn)
  }, [])

  return (
      <div>
          <div id='viewerContainer'></div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Viewer
```

**viewer-helper**

```
import axios from "axios";

const Autodesk = window.Autodesk;

const url_base = 'http://localhost:8080/'
const getToken = async () =>{
  const {data} = await axios.get(url_base + 'api/forge/oauth')
  return data
}

export const initializeViewer = async (urn) => {

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    console.log('document loaded')
    // A document contains references to 3D and 2D viewables.
    var viewables = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry'}, true);
    if (viewables.length === 0) {
        console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
        return;
    }

    // Choose any of the avialble viewables
    var initialViewable = viewables[0];
    var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
    var modelOptions = {
        sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
    };

    var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
    viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
  }

  /**
   * Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load() failuire callback.
   */
  function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
    console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
  }

  /**
   * viewer.loadModel() success callback.
   * Invoked after the model's SVF has been initially loaded.
   * It may trigger before any geometry has been downloaded and displayed on-screen.
   */
  function onLoadModelSuccess(model) {
    console.log('onLoadModelSuccess()!');
    console.log('Validate model loaded: ' + (viewer.model === model));
    console.log(model);
  }

  /**
   * viewer.loadModel() failure callback.
   * Invoked when there's an error fetching the SVF file.
   */
  function onLoadModelError(viewerErrorCode) {
    console.error('onLoadModelError() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
  }

  const token = await getToken()

  const viewerOptions = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    accessToken: token,
    api: 'derivativeV2',
  };
  var viewerContainer = document.getElementById('viewerContainer')
  var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerContainer, {})

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(viewerOptions, () => {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${urn}`, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  })
}
```

What could be my mistake?

Comment: I don't believe you need to `setHeader`, and from Autodesk side, this is allowed... can you please quickly try in incognito mode? (or clear local cache)

Comment: I tried as you suggested with incognito and clearing the cache and got the same error.

Comment: looking again at your code... what's the version that you're using? v7? your code seems different from what I would expect, see this vanilla sample: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui?id=forgeviewerjs

Comment: For authenticating I'm using `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate` from the documentation, but I'm not using modelDerivative because I already have the translated model

Comment: the error you mentioned is on the Viewer, not on the Authentication, right? the link I mentioned above is for the Viewer v7

Comment: I think that the error is in the viewer, I'll check your suggestion